# Generate code file using plist during build phase

Tags: iphone, ios4, xcode4

I am new to iPhone Programming. I need solution to for my problem.

The problem is, I am developing one application, which contains different set of UI screens and each screen contains different set of images. The images I want to use for UI screens , I am getting the file names from plist. Because we want to give this application to different set of customers, so that they update the plist with images name to get different look for the application,

But with the above method, I am  reading the plist every time when the application starts, to get the images name. Because of that the application becoming slow. So I want a solution for this, like  during build phase reading data from plist and generate the code with the images file names. So that i use the code file to read files names. I am just assuming this solution. I am not sure about this.

Can you please help me the solution

Comment: I don't think that reading a plist will take much time. post some code for reading plist file.

Comment: I agree with Rahul. This can not take a lot of time to parse your plist. Maybe the way you read it can be improved. Tell us more about his structure... Do you have all your clients data inthere ?

Answer (score 0):

Why din't you use the same filenames for every client ? They will just have to replace the files and give them the right names. Like this, you won't have to change anything in your code...

Comment: Ya. I can use this solution. But customers wants to follow the above procedure. Please let me know, if you know any thing about this

Comment: With the your solution mentioned above, customer can modify any images by adding to project. But we want allow customers to modify particular images. That's why thinking other solution.